# add element to ordered array in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, coffeescript

I have a sorted array, which I add elements to as the server gives them to me. The trouble I'm having is determining where to place my new element and then placing it in the same loop

in javascript this would look like this

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i){
   if( element_to_add < array[i]){
      array.splice(i,0,element_to_add);
      break;
   }
}
```

The problem is that in coffee script I dont have access to the counter, so I cant tell it to splice my array at the desired index.

How can I add an element to a sorted array in CoffeeScript?

Comment: How are you iterating over the array now?

Comment: `for element in array` and I also tried rapping some plane javascript code in back-ticks, but it keeps on putting `return` infront once it's compiled

Comment: Assuming your array is not sorted in reverse, that code is wrong - it inserts the element just in the first position. And it forgets to break after having it inserted, so it will loop forever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default `for` loop returns the index as well:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
item = 2

for elem, index in a
    if elem >= item
        a.splice index, 0, item
        break
```

You may want to do a binary search instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Underscore.js (very recommended for these kind of array manipulations), [`_.sortedIndex`](http://underscorejs.org/#sortedIndex), which returns the index at which a value should be inserted into an array to keep it ordered, can come very handy:

```
sortedInsert = (arr, val) ->
  arr.splice (_.sortedIndex arr, val), 0, val
  arr
```

If you're not using Underscore, making your own `sortedIndex` is not that hard either; is's basically a binary search (if you want to keep its complexity as O(log n)):

```
sortedIndex = (arr, val) ->
  low = 0
  high = arr.length
  while low < high
    mid = Math.floor (low + high) / 2
    if arr[mid] < val then low = mid + 1 else high = mid
  low
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, why not save the position, like so,

```
var pos=-1;
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i){
   if( element_to_add < array[i]){

      pos=i; break;
   }
}
if(pos<0)
  array.push(element_to_add);
else array.splice(pos,0,element_to_add);
```